# Openshift CronJob visible on the Overview screen

Tags: openshift, kubernetes-cronjob

Is it possible to make job/cronjob visible on the Overview screen in Openshift Container Platform - Aplication Console - Overview? Amongst other services and their pods?

Currently I can see job/cronjob PODs only on

Aplication Console - Applications -> Pods

Cluster Console -> Workloads -> Cron Jobs / Jobs

I found this post https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-jobs/ especially this screenshot https://i1.wp.com/blog.openshift.com/wp-content/uploads/jobs.jpg?ssl=1 which I am not able to reproduce but maybe that's an old version ?

I am using Openshift version 3.11